# Sub menu in main menu items not showing

Tags: css, wordpress

I would need some help since I have the same issue on two WP twin websites where I use the same theme (Newmagz), not longer purchased, and so not supported. All submenus in the main menu are just not showing. I checked on the code through Chrome's and Safari's DevTools, and I see the submenu is there, though I cannot figure out why it is not showing. It seems to be definitely a CSS issue, but after many attempts, I am not able to identify the culprit.

The CSS code ruling the main menu's hover is as follows:

```js
$('.site-navigation .menu-item-has-children').on('hover', function() {
  $(this).children('.sub-menu').stop().slideToggle('fast');
})
```

```css
.site-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children ul.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    z-index: 50;
}

.site-navigation > ul > li.menu-item-has-children:hover:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 43px;
    left: 50%;
}

.site-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children ul.sub-menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

nav#main-menu.site-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children ul.sub-menu li:hover a {
    background: #c51818;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id ="main-menu" class="site-navigation">
  <ul>
    <li class="menu-item-has-children">
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
        <li>c</li>
        <li>d</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item-has-children">
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
        <li>c</li>
        <li>d</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Thanks so much in advance for helping!

Comment: Please try to provide a minimal reproducible example of your problem.

Comment: @AnsonYeung Thanks for your reply; what do you exactly mean by "reproducible example)? The problem is just the following: the hover css function does not work for a reason I cannot find out. Here is the website which does not work properly: http://www.azimuthjournal.com/ - At the "About" main menu item.

Comment: The thing is that no one will take a look at your website. There is way too much unrelated code. Minimal reproducible example is the code required so we can see the problem you described. Not including a ton crap of other code that we don't need to care about.

Comment: @AnsonYeung Thanks for clarifying. I edited accordingly and according to my few notions about hover and js. I was afraid of cutting out some parts of the code that would be involved. Let me know if now it is fine. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In `.site-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children ul.sub-menu`, there is a `display: none;` for no reason. Next time you can check from your browser that which element isn't showing and you know something is wrong with it.

```css
.site-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children ul.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    display: none; /* remove this line */
    z-index: 50;
}
```

```js
$('.site-navigation .menu-item-has-children').on('hover', function() {
  $(this).children('.sub-menu').stop().slideToggle('fast');
})
```

```css
.site-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children ul.sub-menu {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 50;
}

.site-navigation > ul > li.menu-item-has-children:hover:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 43px;
    left: 50%;
}

.site-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children ul.sub-menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

nav#main-menu.site-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children ul.sub-menu li:hover a {
    background: #c51818;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id ="main-menu" class="site-navigation">
  <ul>
    <li class="menu-item-has-children">
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
        <li>c</li>
        <li>d</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item-has-children">
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
        <li>c</li>
        <li>d</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your advice. Sadly, I am afraid this does not help to fix the issue. Indeed the display:none rule is meant to hide the submenu until the user hovers over the menu, so that the submenu expands. If I remove that line, I only make the entire submenu to being and to remain expanded along with the main part of the menu. I need to make the hover function work, I guess.